# Is a CSS background image loaded on mobile when mobile media query uses a different image?

Tags: css, media-queries

Say I have `body{background: url(image1.jpg)}` by default and I also have a media query for mobile (active when viewport width is less than 600px) which sets some `image2.jpg` image to the same `body` element.

On mobile, will `image1.jpg` still be loaded then replaced by the media query by `image2.jpg`?

Comment: No, only the mobile image is loaded.

Comment: Only Image2.jpg is loaded if you are using media query for mobile (active when viewport width is less than 600px) as media query override original css for image background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, only the mobile image is loaded. It's actually very simple to demonstrate this. Resize the snippet window to below 768px before running it, wait for the background to load, then resize it to fullscreen, you can see the desktop background is loaded anew:

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/96918/pexels-photo-96918.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 748px){
  body{
    background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/27714/pexels-photo-27714.jpg');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo"></div>
```

Since user @Johannes doesn't agree, I will give a more solid proof.

**This is before I expand the window:**
[image]

**And this is after: (the background is now white because the image has not finished loading)**
[image]

Comment: Isn't it conceivable that when upsizing window the big image is loaded a second time? I mean that's kind of an indirect proof that you're showing here rather than a direct proof IMO.

Comment: No, I'm showing here the network history of the page. When the window is opened in mobile viewport, only the mobile image is *requested* from the server, only when I resize the viewport to desktop does the second request occur.

Comment: Ah OK then you're right, and it seems this fact is little known too.

Answer (score 1):

Only `image2.png` is loaded(gets into `viewport`). That is the reason for `media query`. Just the same way your `div` is rearranged or restyled with `media query` so are `urls`. The changes would only occur when it reaches the stated `viewport`. 
EDIT: I was misunderstood when i used "loaded". What i meant was. both files are loaded but the one with the specified `query` is `displayed`.

Comment: that's not true: both rules apply to the small screen, the second one overwrites the first one, but AFTER the image from the first rule has already been  loaded. That's why mobile-first exists.

Comment: That what i meant by loaded. Sorry about the confusion. Meant to say displayed

Comment: So both are downloaded by the client right? But the answer below seems to demontrate the exact opposite, could you comment on it please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both images are loaded, which means bandwidth is wasted. The reason: Both rules apply to the small screen, the second one overwrites the first one, but only  AFTER the image from the first rule has already been  loaded.

The reason for the term CSS = Cascading Style Sheet is that one rule after the other is followed. If a later rule overwrites an earlier one, that's normal, but still the earlier one is "obeyed" at first. CSS doesn't wait until all rules are read and then calculates a result, it reads one after the other. So everything that's not in media queries is always read, and if that contains a background-image, it is loaded (also if it's not displayed due to subsequent rules).

To avoid this, you can use a **mobile-first approoach**: First (without media queries) writing the rule for the small screen and then - in a media query only for screens above 600px) loading the big image. In this case the big image will be ignored (and not loaded) by small devices.

Comment: Your answer lack credit and/or proof. Please provide proof that both images are loaded. I on the other hand actually have proof that only 1 of them is loaded in that particular setting.